# Mercurial equivalent of git whatchanged?

Tags: git, mercurial, diff

I want to get similar output of the Git command:

```
$ git whatchanged <old_rev>..<new_rev> --pretty=oneline --name-status
```

I read that `hg outgoing` can help, but it doesn't have anything related to revisions in its help page:

`$ hg diff <old_rev>..<new_rev>` gave the differences, but the output is:

```
diff -r d3ed0d3eb928 -r 63329069147f hello.rb
--- a/hello.rb  Tue Jul 31 16:52:40 2012 +0530
+++ b/hello.rb  Wed Aug 01 11:15:33 2012 +0530
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-print "Hello"
+print "Hello World"
```

while I need something similar to:

```
bb3b9a6bc00b7203ab6491dbd062641fa60efb95 Fix for #4 and other small errors
M       .gitignore
A       config.ru
D       db/database.db
M       views/setup.haml
1c4ff29e5c7fc707c6fe314c060cd1935b300dd9 Added keyboard shortcuts and reload
M       README.md
A       public/javascript/keys.js
d0755d0b54cb4129fbf7730fe0bdf21a3996e224 Basic player completed
M       README.md
D       public/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js
...
```

which I get with `git whatchanged 1c4ff29e5c7fc707c6fe314c060cd1935b300dd9 bb3b9a6bc00b7203ab6491dbd062641fa60efb95 --pretty=oneline --name-status`

Answer (score 2):

You could give the `changelog` style a try. It doesn’t look exactly the same of course, but it does list the files that were touched by the commit, which I reckon is what you are looking for. Examples:

```
hg log --style changelog
hg outgoing --style changelog
```

And as Christian said, you can customise the exact output to infinity using templates. For more information see [`hg help templating`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#template-usage).

Comment: p.s. I just came up with this ugly bastard: `hg log -l 10 --template "{node}\n" | xargs -I{} echo 'hg log -r {} --template "{node} {desc|firstline}\n"; hg status --change {}' | bash`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hg log` for this and [customize the output with a template](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html).

Example:

```
hg log -r <old_rev>:<new_rev> --template "{node} {desc}\n{files}\n\n"
```

This will look *similar* to your Git example.
The list of files doesn't look the same, though (no line breaks).

I never tried it myself, but it's also possible to customize the output with **styles** (similar to templates, but you save the style in a file and just refer to it by the name).
The documentation for this is on the same link I posted above, at the bottom of the page.
Apparently, it's possible to put line breaks between the files as well (there's an example for this on the page).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way of getting which files have changed, but you're not too worried about the formatting being like git, then I quite like the diffstat switch on any of the commands that normally print diffs.

```
# hg in --stat
# hg out --stat
# hg diff -r <old_rev>:<new_rev> --stat
... and a load more
```

It's not exactly the same info. It's not per changeset, and it doesn't say if a file is added / modified / deleted, but on the other hand it gives some idea of the extent of changes.